# AD/LDAP Authentication for a Non-Service account

Tags: authentication, ldap

I'm setting up an app using Java and JAAS so testing the AD/LDAP connection from the command line first. LDAP is not new to me and I thought I understood it but am beginning to reconsider. A service account authenticates but a general employee does not. :-(

I can authenticate using a service account with username "ldap", whose password I know, returning the dn and sAMAccountName of the kcarson account:

```
++ ldapsearch -vx -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no \
-H ldap://21.10.10.50:389 \
-b OU=MyUsers,DC=radical,DC=com \
-D ldap \
-W '(samAccountName=kcarson)' samaccountname

Enter LDAP Password:
dn: CN=Kevin Carson,OU=Phoenix,OU=OutsideTheLines,OU=MyUsers,DC=radical,DC=com
sAMAccountName: kcarson
```

But if I do the same using the username "kcarson" (whose password I know) I receive a failure:

```
++ ldapsearch -vx -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no \
-H ldap://21.10.10.50:389 \
-b OU=MyUsers,DC=radical,DC=com \
-D kcarson \
-W '(samAccountName=kcarson)' samaccountname

Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
        additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839
```

I've also tried using the full dn instead of "kcarson" with the same unsuccessful result. According to [Username and Password for LDAP Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706454/username-and-password-for-ldap-authentication) this should be successful unless *"If any of this fails... it's a login failure"*.

So, if this is a login failure then, AFAIK:

- Either the username or password are incorrect, or
- kcarson does not have authority to authenticate

Are there any other reasons this could be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search Request requires a FDN or when using Microsoft Active Directory you may use some of [Ambiguous Name Resolution (ANR)](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Ambiguous%20Name%20Resolution). So you could use any of the following:

- Fully Distinguished Name:CN=Kevin Carson,OU=Phoenix,OU=OutsideTheLines,OU=MyUsers,DC=radical,DC=com
- userPrincipleName: kcarson@radical.com
- NetBiosName String: (RADICAL\kcarson)
- ObjectGuid: {ca2e693f-6280-4589-9376-b3707345d3ad}

So the samAccountName name is not an option using ANR.

So something like this should work:

```
ldapsearch -vx -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no \
-H ldap://21.10.10.50:389 \
-b OU=MyUsers,DC=radical,DC=com \
-D kcarson@radical.com \
-W \
'(samAccountName=kcarson)' samaccountname
```

Happy LDAPing and Happy Holidays!

Comment: The full email address worked! I thought I had tried every conceivable combination for the username but must have missed this one. Muchos thankos, and Hoppy Hallidays!

Comment: Now I'm really confused. The second time I tried the command that worked before, it failed. How is that possible! Could there be a bad config on the AD side?

Comment: Not Sure. Remember it is the userPrincipalName, not email address Nothing says they are the same.